# How to enable user to switch between ggplot2 and gVis graphs in R Shiny?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm making an app that allows the user to upload any csv file and the app will graph it. I'd like to allow the user to switch between graph styles, gVis and ggplot. The graphs work as implemented by themselves, but I can't seem to figure out how to enable the user to switch them with a checkboxInput (input$switchLine). I'll post only the sample code relative to the problem at hand, let me know if you need more info.

I've tried things like in server:

```
if (input$switchLine) {
    output$gvisLine
} else {
    output$plotLine
}
```

But the problem is that in the ui.R, ggplot line uses plotOutput while gVis uses html Output.

ui.R (I've commented out the gVis line as I only know how to plot one at a time right now)

```
library(shiny)

dataset <- list('Upload a file'=c(1))

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel(''),

  sidebarPanel(
    wellPanel(
        selectInput('xLine', 'X', names(dataset)),
        selectInput('yLine', 'Y', names(dataset),  multiple=T)
    ),
    wellPanel(
        checkboxInput('switchLine', 'Switch to gVis')  
    )
  ),
  mainPanel( 
     tabPanel("Line Graph", plotOutput('plotLine', height="auto"), value="line"),  
     #Below is the gvis Line           
     #tabPanel("Line Graph", htmlOutput("gvisLine"), value="line")

  )
))
```

server.R

```
library(reshape2)
library(googleVis)
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(scales)
require(xlsx)
require(xlsxjars)
require(rJava)
require(shiny)

options(shiny.maxRequestSize=-1)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

if (is.null(input$file))
      return(NULL)
    else if (identical(input$format, 'CSV'))
      return(read.csv(input$file$datapath))
    else if (identical(input$format, 'XLSX'))
      return(read.xlsx2(input$file$datapath, input$sheet))
    else
      return(read.delim(input$file$datapath))
})

observe({
    df <- data()
    str(names(df))

    updateSelectInput(session, 'xLine', choices = names(df))
    updateSelectInput(session, 'yLine', choices = names(df))
}
})

output$gvisLine<- renderGvis( {
    tempX <- input$xLine
    tempY <- input$yLine
    if (is.null(data()))
      return(NULL)
    if (is.null(tempY))
      return(NULL)

    gvisLineChart(data(),xvar=tempX,yvar=tempY,
                  options=list(
                    title=paste("",tempX," VS ",tempY,""),
                    titlePosition='out',
                    hAxis="{slantedText:'true',slantedTextAngle:45}",
                    titleTextStyle="{color:'black',fontName:'Courier'}",
                    legend="{color:'black',fontName:'Courier'}",
                    fontSize="10",
                    chartArea="{left:40,top:30,width:'90%',height:'85%'}",            
                    height=700, width=1100))

  })

  output$plotLine <- renderPlot(height=650, units="px", {

    tempX <- input$xLine
    tempY <- input$yLine

    if (is.null(data()))
      return(NULL)
    if (is.null(tempY))
      return(NULL)

    widedata <- subset(data(), select = c(tempX, tempY))
    melted <- melt(widedata, id = tempX)
    p <- ggplot(melted, aes_string(x=names(melted)[1], y="value", group="variable", color="variable")) + geom_line() + geom_point()
    p <- p + opts(axis.text.x=theme_text(angle=45, hjust=1, vjust=1))
    p <- p + labs(title=paste("",tempX," VS ",tempY,""))

    print(p)


  })
})
```

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
   conditionalPanel(
                      condition = "input.switchLine == false",
                      plotOutput('plotLine', height="auto")
                    ),
                    conditionalPanel(
                      condition = "input.switchLine == true",
                      htmlOutput("gvisLine")
                    )
```

or something similar in `ui.R`

Comment: I've tried this before and gotten an error because I need to use tabPanels (i only put a small sample of my total code). When I try to graph the code you put above with tabPanels, I get an argument is of lenghth zero error.

Comment: Seems to work for me inside tabPanels ([for example](https://gist.github.com/jcheng5/9bb8f87fc58deb15720b)). If you have a (minimal) reproducible example please post it!